# How to apply different styles based on the browser location path name?

Tags: reactjs

```
const activeStyle = {
  border: '1px solid transparent',
  borderColor: '#e4e6e8', 
  borderBottomColor: '#fff', 
  marginBottom: '-1px',
  cursor: 'default'
}

const notActive = {
  cursor: 'pointer'
}

class LoginSignup extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const pathName = this.props.history.location.pathname;
    return (
        <div style={{ pathName === '/login' ? ...activeStyle : ...notActive  }}>
           <Link to='/login'><span>Log in</span></Link>
         </div>
         <div style={{ pathName === '/signup' ? ...activeStyle : ...notActive  }}>
            <Link to='/signup'><span>Sign up</span></Link>
           </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default withRouter(LoginSignup);
```

I want to apply different styles based on the location path name. How to do that? I tried ternary operator inside style attribute but it shows Unexpted token, expected , error.

Comment: Is there some error coming or styles are not getting applied?

Comment: An error, Unexpected token, expected ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write it like so:

```
<div style={pathName === '/login' ? activeStyle : notActive}>...</div>
```

If you need to concat some styles, I would do something along the lines:

```
<div style={pathName === '/login' ? activeStyle : { ...activeStyle, ...notActive}}>...</div>
```

For readability, maybe rename the `activeStyle` to `defaultStyle`.

Comment: Thanks @janhartmann. I have also another style props how to apply both?

Comment: Thanks again man. I want to apply like this one <div style={ pathName === '/login' ? {...activeStyle} : {...notActive}, { marginRight: '10px', ...defaultStyle }}>

Comment: Consider using a className instead of inline styling for better maintainability over time :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
  you can try the code like below.

     const pathName = this.props.history.location.pathname;
     let headerlink='';
     if(pathName=='/login'){
       headerlink=<div style={{...activeStyle }}>
               <Link to='/login'><span>Log in</span></Link>
             </div>
     }else{
      headerlink=<div style={{...notActive }}>
                <Link to='/signup'><span>Sign up</span></Link>
               </div>;
    }
    return headerlink;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your spread operator is incorrect you need to spread it within object. One of the following two approaches will work.

```
class LoginSignup extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const pathName = this.props.history.location.pathname;
    return (
        <div style={{ pathName === '/login' ? activeStyle : notActive  }}>
           <Link to='/login'><span>Log in</span></Link>
         </div>
         <div style={{ pathName === '/signup' ? activeStyle : notActive  }}>
            <Link to='/signup'><span>Sign up</span></Link>
           </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

OR

```
class LoginSignup extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const pathName = this.props.history.location.pathname;
    return (
        <div style={{ pathName === '/login' ? {...activeStyle} : {...notActive}  }}>
           <Link to='/login'><span>Log in</span></Link>
         </div>
         <div style={{ pathName === '/signup' ? {...activeStyle} : {...notActive}  }}>
            <Link to='/signup'><span>Sign up</span></Link>
           </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```